# Redis: Atomic get and conditional set

Tags: lua, redis, conditional-statements, atomic

I'd like to perform an atomic `GET` in Redis, and if the value returned is equal to some expected value, I'd like to do a `SET`, but I want to chain all of this together as one atomic operation. (I'm trying to set a flag that indicates whether any process is writing data to disk, as only one process may be permitted to do so.)

Is it possible to accomplish this with Redis?

I have seen documentation on `MULTI` operations but I haven't seen conditional operations i `MULTI` operations. Any suggestions others can offer with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can do it all redis-side with a Lua script: https://redis.io/commands/eval

Comment: @ChrisTanner make this into an answer, and I'll upvote

Comment: In case others also wish to create a write lock, this is great reading: https://redis.io/topics/distlock

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do both the GET and set operations on the redis server itself using [Lua scripts](https://redis.io/commands/eval). They're atomic and allow you to add logic too.

Comment: thanks for your thought. Do you happen to know of any examples of tutorials on simple Lua scripts in Redis that are good for beginners? I haven't worked with Lua before, so would like to start with some real basics...

Comment: These two pages got me on the right track to implement something just like you're looking for https://www.redisgreen.net/blog/intro-to-lua-for-redis-programmers/ and https://www.compose.com/articles/a-quick-guide-to-redis-lua-scripting/

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [redlock-py](https://github.com/SPSCommerce/redlock-py), an implementation of the redlock algorithm that the Redis docs recommend for creating write locks: https://redis.io/topics/distlock. The linked article is fantastic reading for anyone looking to create similar write locks in Redis.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post looking for a similar type of function, but I didn't see any options that appealed to me. I opted instead to write a small module in Rust that provides this exact type of operation:

https://github.com/KennethWilke/redis-setif

With this module you would do this via:

```
SETIF <key> <expected> <new>
HSETIF <key> <field> <expected> <new>
```

Answer (score 0):

[redis-if](https://github.com/nodeca/redis-if) - lua script for "conditional transactions". More convenient than WATCH + MULTY.

You can pass any combination of conditions & followed commands as json object:

```js
const Redis = require('ioredis')

const redis = new Redis()

redis.defineCommand('transaction', { lua: require('redis-if').script, numberOfKeys: 0 })

await redis.set('custom-state', 'initialized')
await redis.set('custom-counter', 0)

// this call will change state and do another unrelated operation (increment) atomically
let success = await redis.transaction(JSON.stringify({
  if: [
    // apply changes only if this process has acquired a lock
    [ 'initialized', '==', [ 'sget', 'custom-state' ] ]
  ],
  exec: [
    [ 'set', 'custom-state', 'finished' ],
    [ 'incr', 'custom-counter' ]
  ]
}))
```

With this script we removed all custom scripting from our projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by SET command, with these 2 arguments, which according to the docs [here](https://redis.io/commands/set/):

> GET - return the old string stored at key, or nil if key did not
> exist.
>
> NX - Only set the key if it does not already exist.

Since Redis doesn't execute any command while another command is running - you have the 2 operations in an atomic manner.

Comment: important: Starting with Redis version 7.0.0: Allowed the NX and GET options to be used together.